# mongodb logpath folder permission change

Tags: mongodb

I need some advice on MongoDB Log path permission. Currently, I have 755 permission

on /var/log/mongodb . Our internal auditing will not allow having 755 permission on base folder /var/log..

When i change it to 640, my Mongod process failing with permission error even though my /var/log/MongoDB has 755 privilege.

Again I switch back /var/log to 755 I can able to start my mongod process. is it known behavior.

Kindly advice I need to give a rationale for possible mitigation to get overriding approval

Answer (score 0):

You can have 640 for /var/log and 755 for /var/log/mongod.log. But you have to start mongod as a root user.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I am running my mongod with mongodb user.. How do i change it to root.. this will lot of , manual changes.

Comment: You have to login as root in your server and then have to start mongod.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs let me try and update here